# JSONP Request returning correct value but not showing in Callback Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp, jquery-callback

Thanks to this forum, i was able to access cross domain rest api through JSONP and callback function concepts.

My requirement is to show the JSON Output returned from my Web Service in HTML.
I am calling the REST API and i am getting the correct output(Developer Tools) but i am not getting that in any variable in the code.

The data variable in the callback function isn't getting any value.
If i analyze the Developer Tools, the output is coming in an appended URI
http://xxxx:8000/sap/bc/zrest_demo?sap-client=200&callback=&callback=restapi&_=1466389824755

The reason i believe is, i found that callback function is getting fired first and then the web service on the backend is getting called. How can we call the web service first and then execute the callback method.

The following is my code:

```
 <body>    

 <div>  

 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <button onclick="callSAPRestService('OK')">Click me</button>

 <script>

        function callSAPRestService(value1) 

        {                                                    
                 $.ajax({            

                url: "http://xxxx:8000/sap/bc/zrest_demo?sap-client=200&callback=",
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                jsonpCallback: 'restapi',
                jsonp: 'callback',

                  });

        }

        function restapi(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
 </script>
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: do you have some accented character in your response like 'é' or 'à' ?? if it is yes so you should set the utf-8 response parameter

Comment: Have you tried specifying `success : restapi` in the `$.ajax()` options?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I found that the output is coming in a added URI
&callback=restapi&_=1466389824755 added with the original URI

Answer (score 0):

You may need to have a separate function that iterates over it.

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   url: 'http://xxxx:8000/sap/bc/zrest_demo?sap-client=200&callback=',
   data: {
      query: value,
      cb: 'callback'
    },
   dataType: 'jsonp',
});
```

In this case, `cb: 'callback'` is the name of your function.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you just return the data when the call is successful? For example:

```
callRestService: function() {
    var result = null;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'someurl',
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data) {
            result = data;
        }
    });
   return result;
}
```

Comment: The results variable returns Null, and i am still getting the data in an extended URI : http:/XXXX:8000/sap/bc/zrest_demo?sap-client=200&callback=jQuery16202293787001975638_1466390509710&_=1466390513676